# Python 3 - Replacing part of a string with information from the string

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, parsing

I have a python project where I am essentially coding a custom language, and for it I need a function that can replace user entered strings with different data, for example random numbers (It's hard to explain what I want to do c:)

An example of this would be that the user types into the command line:

```
j@dev-box$ file write hi.txt {RANDOM_INT[1, 20]}
```

and the function would  run like:

```
parseOutput = parseFunction(userInputString) # userInputString = "file write hi.txt {RANDOM_INT[1,20]}
```

then parseOutput would equal `file write hi.txt 14` , with the random number in place of the {RANDOM_INT[x, x]} tag

I hope I made what I am looking for clear enough as it is difficult to explain.

Comment: Please could the downvoter explain why he/she gave my post a downvote? I would appreciate their help to improve my post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, instead of using the Python template string (which are powerful but limited) I suggest you using [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) templates.

This template engine is well-known for developing web applications.

To implement your custom language, you can use **filters**. Here is an example:

First import the required modules:

```
import random

from jinja2.environment import Environment
```

Define a filter to calculate a random number, like this:

```
def random_int(value, x, y):
    return "{0}".format(random.randint(x, y))
```

*note: the **value** parameter is not used here.*

Define a Jinja environment and add your custom filter:

```
env = Environment()
env.filters["RANDOM_INT"] = random_int
```

You can then use it like this (you have to slightly change the user input to conform to Jinja template syntax):

```
user_input = 'file write hi.txt {{ "" | RANDOM_INT(1, 10) }}'
template = env.from_string(user_input)
result = template.render()
```

The result:

```
print(result)
# file write hi.txt 9
```

Avantages: Jinja can check the syntax and missing formats for you.

**EDIT: more examples**

You can change the environment configuration to use
single curly braces instead of double:

```
env = Environment(variable_start_string="{", variable_end_string="}")
```

Instead of creating a custom filter, you can use builtin functions and filters.
Eg.: use the `range()` function with the `random`filter:

```
user_input = 'file write hi.txt { range(10) | random }'
template = env.from_string(user_input)
result = template.render()
print(result)
```

finally, you can extend the global context with your own functions

```
env = Environment(variable_start_string="{", variable_end_string="}")
env.globals["RANDOM_INT"] = random.randint

user_input = 'file write hi.txt { RANDOM_INT(1, 10) }'
template = env.from_string(user_input)
result = template.render()
print(result)
```

Comment: Wow, this looks really powerful! Will have a proper tinker when I get home :)

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem perfectly. Will upvote and try to add as accepted answer! Just a quick question though; my project is designed to run on python with no packages installed. I have extracted the jinja2 folder and packaged it with my project, and it works, but I am wondering if this is legal? Thanks, Jay. PS: If it isn't, then I didn't manage it :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `str.find` functionality from Python. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

Example:

```
def parseFunction(input):
     index = input.find('{') # or look for more i.e. find('{RANDOM_INT')
     return input[:index] + ' ' + randomInt # remember to add the space
```

You can generate the `randomInt` using `random.randInt` from the built-in library `random.py`. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)

Comment: Thanks,  but I was looking to grab the randInt parameters from the input :) . I'll have a tinker with this and see if I can adapt it

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you needed?

```
import re
import random
def parseFunction(string):
    matches = re.match('.*\{r\[(\d+),(\d+)\]\}.*',string)
    rand = random.randint(int(matches.groups()[0]), int(matches.groups()[1]))
    result = re.sub('\{r\[(\d+),(\d+)\]\}',str(rand),string)
    return result
```

Comment: This looks good (cant test it for a few hours though) but it seems to be for python 2?

Comment: Hmm. Seems to return a nonetype error? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    parseFunction("hi {r[1, 2]}")
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 3, in parseFunction
    rand = random.randint(int(matches.groups()[0]), int(matches.groups()[1]))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'